# Wait until dispatch is returned some value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(action.fetchQuestions(location.state));
    renderAnswer();
  }, []);
```

I want to wait until dispatch is done because i am mapping through the dispatched results. so when ever i try to follow the above method it throws error saying cant map through undefined.

Comment: If you fetch from an api  you can make the function asynchronous ,
But share more code

Comment: Where/how are you using the resulting state?  What is `renderAnswer()`?  Generally you use `dispatch` to update state, then elsewhere in the component you render based on state.  The framework automatically re-renders when the new state is available.  It's not clear what you're trying to do here.  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: If you're not using the thunk pattern it might cause problems. This could help https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-logic-thunks

Answer (score 0):

Use hook "useSelector", it triggers rerender on changes state.

```
const questions = useSelector(state => state.questions);
```

Comment: const { question, isLoading, hasErrors } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.questions
  ); yeah using that one